# Connect an ANDROID APP via bluetooth to two different Serial Profile Ports (RFCOMM channels) provided by the same BT device

Tags: android, bluetooth, serial-port, channel, rfcomm

**Context:**
I have a BT device that provides two BT Serial Port Profiles, each of those uses a different RFCOMM channel. When I pair that device with my PC I can see those two profiles as two different COM ports and I can connect and interact with those ports independently.

I would like to do the same with an Android App. I would like to get my App connected to two different Serial Port Profiles provided by my BT device. 
By looking on the Web I have found just reference about connecting via BT Service UUID to a single port.

**Question:**
Is it possible to connect an Android App to two different Serial Port Profiles (with two different RFCOMM Channels) provided by the same BT device ? How ?